# Remove 'Persian (standard) keyboard (FAS)' keyobard layout in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I've added Persian keyboard to my Windows 10. However it added two keyboard layout which one of them is not my option and make troubles for me while switching between languages.

[image]

I could not find nowhere to remove this layout. Does anybody have an idea how can I remove 'Persian (standard) keyboard (FAS)' from my language options (I still want to have `Persian Keyboard (FA)`)?

Here is the screenshot of language options:
[image: s-]

Comment: I could remove it by deleting `0x00050429` entry in Registry path: `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile\Fa`